# static class with so many request at same time

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0

I created a static ip and log class.
the ip class find out the users ip address and log class log it into a text file.
every thing work just fine but i wonder what happens if so many requests came at a same time?
i mean the both classes are static and base on static classes it causes problem.
how can i managed them?
here is my ip class:

```
    public static class IP
    {
        public static string IP()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

            string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                {
                    return addresses[0];
                }
            }

            return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
    }
}
```

and here part of my log class which write into the text file:

```
        private static void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        string filePath = FilePath();
        CreateFile(filePath);
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter log = File.AppendText(filePath))
                log.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //If can not access to file do nothing
            //throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem(s) have you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to run into contention problems due to your classes being static. Your IP.IP() method class is pure (i.e. it does not change the state of anything) and contains no locks, so there is no chance of there being any contention there.

You do potentially have problems in WriteLine due to the fact that you are probably writing your log file on the same thread as you are doing your work. That means the file write is acting as a lock since only one write can occur at any one time.

What you want is to log to a queue and then to write that queue on a separate thread; that is a classic producer-consumer pattern.

Alternatively you could avoid reinventing the wheel and use an existing logging framework that will handle these things for you like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: Though log is again a local variable, but i agree , this may not be the best and most performance oriented way of writing logs. You may even want to check bit factory logger, that's really good:

http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog/Sample.aspx

Comment: Log is local, but it abstracts the file on the disk which is global.

Comment: Multiple writers writing to a file will not be an issue. just that you may end up having jumbled logs. Idea remains that will not have an issue with multiple writers accessing it, though the log frameworks like log4net makes it much stable system

Answer (score 0):

**It will work fine**, because you don't have any public variable which will be kept in memory and changing on every time class is accessed.

So as the method ends, the scope of your variables will be finished. 
However if they are in memory, they will not be effected by how many users use it at the same time, and there will be no mess.

Answer (score 0):

Streamwriter has a default of 4kb buffer which can be modified if needed as defined by:

```
public StreamWriter(
    Stream stream,
    Encoding encoding,
    int bufferSize
)
```

More than likely, your computer (including disk access) is most likely a lot faster than your internet access.

Comment: You really think that? Most servers still have mechanical disks and are often raided for resilience rather than performance. The disk is almost always an issue.

Comment: That is true in many respects. In my own experience it has not been a problem. when you think about how much data is being uploaded to the client in the form of a webpage, and how much information is sent back, and with what is being sent back, how much of it is logged. There is quite a bit of latency between sending and receiving. Assuming not a huge amount of info is being logged per request received, if there are too many requests, then the web server will time out before any buffer overloading to a log entry. Again, that is just my experience.

Comment: To add to that, if I get an error writing to a log, then I have the logging routine send me an error email. To date, I have not received an error email. So that is an additional backup to my logging.